# How to call an async function with a non-static reference in `poll` in rust?

Tags: rust, future, lifetime, rust-futures

I've encountered an obstacle when trying to implement `Future`.

I need to `poll` another `async` function in my `poll` function which only takes in `&str`.
It looks something like this:

```rust
async fn make_query(query: &str) -> i32 {
    // Magic happens
    5
}
```

As this is a function from another library I cannot simply change its signature to take ownership of the values.

Now my struct `Executor`, for which I want to implement `Future`, holds a `String` which should be referenced when calling `make_query`:

```rust
struct Executor {
    query: String,
    future: Mutex<Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = i32>>>>>
}

impl Future for Executor {
    type Output = i32;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut lock = self.future.lock().unwrap();

        if let None = *lock {
            // This is where the error occurs
            *lock = Some(Box::pin(make_query(&self.query)))
        }

        let future = lock.as_mut().unwrap();
        pin!(future).poll(cx)
    }
}
```

Now, the purpose of this is that I can `.await` my `Executor` to automatically make the query:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let result = Executor {
        query: "foo".to_string(),
        future: Mutex::new(None)
    }.await;

    println!("Result is {result}");
}
```

Now, apparently the `Mutex` requires that every reference passed to it is `'static`? I got these error messages:

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:26
   |
16 |     fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
   |                       - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
23 |             *lock = Some(Box::pin(make_query(&self.query)))
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

error[E0597]: `self` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:47
   |
16 |     fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
   |             ---- binding `self` declared here
...
23 |             *lock = Some(Box::pin(make_query(&self.query)))
   |                          ---------------------^^^^--------
   |                          |                    |
   |                          |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          cast requires that `self` is borrowed for `'static`
...
29 |     }
   |     - `self` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How do I tell Rust that `Executor` is only dropped when it has been completely polled? I can't change the function signature of `poll` as that would violate the trait specifications.

Or, more likely, what is the correct way to do what I want to do?

Here's a link to the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c35328bfb74c0a0570d8b26024de151e).

PS: I am aware that calling `.await` to execute the query might be considered an 'anti pattern'.

---

## Solution

Checkout [drewtato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76638672/14385360) for an explanation.

The solution (for me) was to remove the `future` field from my struct:

```rust
struct Executor {
    query: String
}
```

and then, instead of implementing `Future`, implement `IntoFuture` which gets implicitly called when using `.await`. Here we can use `async move {}` which moves the value instead of just referencing it.

Note that, at this point, `type IntoFuture = impl Future` is unstable and I thus had to use `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`

```rust
impl IntoFuture for Executor {
    type Output = i32;
    type IntoFuture = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Self::Output>>>;

    fn into_future(self) -> Self::IntoFuture {
        Box::pin(async move {
            make_query(&self.query).await
        })
    }
}
```

Now you can call `.await` on `Executor`:

```rust
#[tokio::main] 
async fn main() {
    let res = Executor {
        query: "foo".into()
    }.await;

    println!("Result is {res}"); // 5
}
```

Comment: Why the `Mutex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make a [self-referential struct, which is not safely possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/6274355).

It looks like you're trying to make this async function `'static`, which is useful if you are trying to spawn it. You can do this by just creating an async block.

```rs
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let s = "foo".to_string();
    
    // This doesn't work since it borrows `s`.
    // let result = tokio::spawn(make_query(&s)).await.unwrap();

    // This works since it moves `s` into the future.
    let result = tokio::spawn(async move {
        make_query(&s).await
    }).await.unwrap();

    println!("Result is {result}");
}
```

This async block is actually self-referential, but async blocks are specifically handled by rust to allow this. If you wanted to create this by hand, you would need unsafe code.

Note that *calling* an async function does no work, only *awaiting* does, so delaying the `make_query` call has no purpose. If you want to do something before `make_query`, you can simply put it in the async block.

I couldn't figure out why you used a mutex. If you needed that for something, add it to the question. It's probably fine to remove it completely.

Every trait object includes a lifetime, so when you declare a trait object without one like `dyn Future<Output = i32>`, it usually becomes `dyn Future<Output = i32> + 'static`. If you wanted to store non-`'static` data inside a trait object, you'd need to add it to your type.

```rs
struct Executor<'f> {
    query: String,
    future: Mutex<Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = i32> + 'f>>>>
}
```

However, this would only be correct if your struct wasn't self-referential.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to use this information to achieve my purpose. I tried passing `async move { make_query(&self.query).await }` to `Box::pin()`, but the error message remains the same: `&mut Self` does not outlive `'static`. Could you show how to implement my specific use-case, please?

Comment: You would use the async block instead of `Executor`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can handle that is by creating a wrapper function that takes an **owned** `String`, does the work, and returns the `String` so you can reuse it. This way, you got a future that contains no lifetime (the Rust compiler handles the self-reference for you), and you can freely store it in the struct:

I'll also point you to [`tokio_util::sync::ReusableBoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/sync/struct.ReusableBoxFuture.html), that allows you to save allocations in cases like that by only allocating the space for the future once. You do not need it in this case since you're only using the future once, but it can be useful in similar cases.